# Названия цветов

Tags: этимология

Мне понятно происхождение только слов "красный", "черный", "сиреневый", "розовый" и, возможно, "коричневый" (если я прав, то от слова "корица"), ну и различных оттенков. А что с основными цветами? Каково происхождение слов "синий", "желтый", "белый", "зеленый", "серый" и т.д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Многие из этих слов имеют древнерусские корни. Некоторые пришли из других языков вместе с растениями. Подробнее:

**Синий.** Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. синь, церк.-слав. синь (др.-греч. πελιδνός, μέλας), укр. си́нiй, белор. сíнi, болг. син, сербохорв. си̑њӣ «сероватый, синий», словенск. sínji, чешск., словацк. siný, польск. siny. Родственно сия́ть (см.) или си́вый, лит. šývas «светлой масти», др.-инд. c̨yāmás «черный, темный», лит. šė́mas, šē̃mаs «пепельного цвета, сероватый». Созвучные фин.-уг. названия: фин. sini «синий цвет», морд. м. śeń, э. seń «синий», мар. šinžiš — то же. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

---

**Желтый.** Из праслав. формы *žьltъ, от которой в числе прочего произошли: русск. жёлтый, укр. жо́втий, болг. жълт, сербохорв. жу̑т, ж. жу́та, словенск. žȏlt, ж. žólta, чешск. žlutý, словацк. žltý, польск. żółty, в.-луж., н.-луж. žołty. Праслав.* žьltъ родственно лит. gel̃tas «желтый», латышск. dzęlts – то же, др.-прусск. gelatynan – то же, греч. χόλος, χολή «желчь», лат. fel (род. п. fellis) «желчь, желчный пузырь» (древняя основа на -n), др.-в.-нем. galla «желчь». од. п. fellis «желчь, желчный пузырь» (древняя основа на -n), др.-в.-нем. galla «желчь». Ср. еще желна́, желчь. С рефлексом др. задненёбного сюда же относится группа слов зо́лото, зелёный. Из праиндоевр. *ghel- «жёлтый, зелёный». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

---

**Белый.** Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. бѣлъ, укр. бíлий, болг. бял, сербохорв. би̏о, биjу̀ела, словенск. bė^ɫ, чешск. bílý, польск. biały, в.-луж., н.-луж. běły. Исконнородственно др.-инд. bhālam «блеск», bhāti «светит, сияет», греч. πεφήσεται «явится» (от φαίνω из *φάνι̯ω), πέφη ̇ ἐφάνη (Гесихий), лит. boiúoti «отливать белым, белеть», латышск. bãls «бледный, блеклый», лит. balas «белый», греч. φαλός λευκός (Гесихий), φάλιος «светлый, белый», кимрск. bal «белолицый», алб. ballë «лоб», др.-исл. báI «огонь», далее лит. balà «болото», báltas «белый». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

---

**Зеленый.** Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. зеленъ (др.-греч. χλωρός, πράσινος), укр. зеле́ний, болг. зеле́н, сербохорв. зѐлен, словенск. zelèn, ж. zeléna, чешск., словацк. zelený, польск. zielony, в.-луж., н.-луж. zеlеnу; восходит к праиндоевр. *ghel-; родственно лит. žãlias, латышск. zal̨š «зеленый», др.-прусск. saligan — то же, лит. želiù, žė́liau, žélti «зарастать»; с др. вокализмом: лит. žolė̃ «трава, зелень», латышск. zale, др.-прусск. sãlin «трава», др.-инд. híranyam «золото», авест. zаrаnуа- — то же, др.-инд. háriṣ, авест. zairi- «желтый, золотистый», лат. helvus «желтоватый» : лит. žel̃vas, žal̃svas «зеленоватый», алб. dhеlрёrё, dhelpnë «лисица». См. также зелье, золото, зола́. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.
От праиндоевр. корня* ghel- также произошли:
англ. yellow, green, gold; староангл. geolu, geolwe
нем. gelb, grün, vergilben, Gold
греч. khole (ср. русск. меланхолия, холера, холерик, хлор и их эквиваленты в англ., нем., и мн. др. языках)
лат. helvus, галло-лат. gilvus
лит. geltonas, zalias, zelvas
санскр. harih, hiranyam
авест. zari
староирл. glass
валл./брет. glas
Кроме того, не исключено родство корня *ghel- с корнем* ghlei- (светиться; ср. англ. gleam, нем. glimmen и т. п.)

---

**Серый.** Происходит от др.-русск., русск.-церк.-слав. сѣръ; ср.: укр. сíрий, болг. сер, се́рей «сало, жир», словенск. sẹr, sẹ́rа «серый, белокурый», др.-чешск. šěrý, чешск., словацк. šerý, польск. szary, в.-луж. šěry, н.-луж. šеrу. Ввиду зап.-слав. š можно говорить только о праслав. *хоirо-. Последнее родственно герм.* haira-, ср. др.-исл. hárr «серый, седой», англос. hár, др.-в.-нем. he^r «достойный, величественный», ирл. сiаr «темный»; далее см. седой. Зап.-слав. формы на š говорят о существовании дифтонгического ě и противоречат сравнению слав. *sěrъ с др.-инд. c̨ārás «пестрый, пятнистый», греч. κηρύλος «голубой зимородок». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Comment: И везде "список литературы". Или уберите слова, или вставьте список.

Comment: Убрал. Помогло?

Comment: Да, спасибо! А то очень уж похоже на некоторые студенческие рефераты, полностью скопированные из интернет, которые их авторы, похоже, сами не читали...